# How do I create a view by joining two tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a PostgreSQL newbie, and I have two tables like this:

1. `Attendees(AttendeeId, Name)`
2. `Couples(CoupleId, AttendeeIdMan, AttendeeIdLady)`

How do I create a view like this?

```
Attendees_Couple(CoupleId, Name_Man, Name_Lady)
```

For now, I came out with something like the below, but then I got stuck.

```
CREATE VIEW Attendees_Couple AS
SELECT a."Name"
FROM "Attendees" a, "Couples" c
WHERE a."AttendeeID" = c."AttendeeIdMan"....
```

Any hint or help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to join with `Attendees` twice:

```
CREATE VIEW "Attendees_Couple" AS
SELECT c."CoupleId",
       a1."Name" AS "Name_Man",
       a2."Name" AS "Name_Lady"
FROM "Couples" AS c
   JOIN "Attendees" AS a1 ON c."AttendeeIdMan"  = a1."AttendeeId"
   JOIN "Attendees" AS a2 ON c."AttendeeIdLady" = a2."AttendeeId";
```

Do yourself a favor and use lower case names!

Comment: Oh yes, +1 for the use of lower case names.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot!
So sad I am not the one who created those tables...